# Which is the best approach to translates the results of a sql query directly to the X and Y axis of a chart

Tags: mysql, sql, charts

I wish to find out the appropriate approaches to translates the results of a sql query directly to the X and Y axis of a chart, when you have multiple columns in the statement. for example
`SELECT city,country,count(*) FROM beer
group by country
having count(*) > 100
order by 2 desc` how should i handle this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't SQL Server since it didn't give an error from that broken group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I think you just want to take your city and country columns and combine them, like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(city , ', ', country) AS x_axis, COUNT(*) as y_axis
FROM beer
GROUP BY city, country
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
ORDER BY country, city;
```